# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'duration' into field when trying to select a property field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

there are alot of questions on this particular error but none caused by trying to select a property field from the serializer, below are my code

```
 # seriliazer.py
    class ProjectActivitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        is_running = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
        duration = serializers.ReadOnlyField() # i am trying to select this particular field to perform some calculation
        
        class Meta:
            model = ProjectActivity
            fields = '__all__'


 class ProjectActivity(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False, 
     max_length=400, default="")
    project = models.ForeignKey(to=Project, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def duration(self):
        """
        get the duration of the activity

        Returns:
            timedelta: duration of the activity
        """
        if self.is_running:
            sec = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - self.start_time
            return str(timedelta(seconds=round(sec.total_seconds())))
        else:
            sec = self.end_time - self.start_time
            return str(timedelta(seconds=round(sec.total_seconds())))
          

    class GetTotalProjectActivityTime(ListAPIView):
        """
        
        """
        serializer_class = ProjectActivitySerializer
        permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOwner|IsAdminUser) # protect the endpoint
    
    
        def get_queryset(self):
            return ProjectActivity.objects.filter(user=self.kwargs['user'], project__id=self.kwargs['project']).values('duration')
            

Just a background to my problem here: i have the below response

    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "is_running": true,
            "duration": "2 days, 5:43:26",
            "description": "worked on developing dashboard endpoint",
            "start_time": "2021-12-22T11:40:49.452935Z",
            "end_time": null,
            "project": 1,
            "user": 1
        }
    ]
```

I want to run a calculation on the duration but the duration field isn't part of my model field but a just property. the duration value is gotten from the duration property of the model and I want to calculate the total duration from the response.

now i am finding it difficult to run the calculation

Comment: For using it in `queryset` you have to `annotate` it using [`F()` annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations).

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: Show the ProjectActivity model?

Comment: @shivankgtm i want to sum up all the duration values

Comment: your duration in resposne looks like a string value but in class method you have returned it as a string of datetime object.

can you edit in question from where you are getting the response. and do you want to calculate the duration from response or from somewhere else

Comment: @IainShelvington made the necessary update

Answer (score 1):

First change the `duration` property to use [cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property), doing so allows you to create an annotation with the same name and not get a conflict when the annotated value is set on the object.

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from django.utils.timezone import now

class ProjectActivity(models.Model):

    @cached_property
    def duration(self):
        return (self.end_time or now()) - self.start_time
```

Now we can annotate a queryset with a `duration` by using the following

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce, Now

queryset = ProjectActivity.objects.annotate(
    end_or_now=Coalesce('end_time', Now()))
).annotate(
    duration=F('end_or_now') - F('start_time')
)
```

This annotation can then be used in further annotations, filters, aggregates, etc

```
from django.db.models import Sum

queryset.aggregate(total_duration=Sum('duration'))
```

Comment: i have tried your solution but I get the below errors AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `project` on serializer `ProjectActivitySerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance. Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'project'.

Comment: @user15317824 is this in your `GetTotalProjectActivityTime` view? If this view is just supposed to return a single total duration then the view shouldn't be a list api view and should have a different serializer that returns the correct field(s)

Comment: this is a ListAPIView, what type of view should i use please?

Comment: can i use APIVIEW inplace of LIstApiView?